# Запись в файл из списка

Tags: java, файлы

1.я заполнил список элементами из файла "test1.txt"

2.удалил дубликаты из списка

3.вывел результат на консоль

4.мне надо результат записать в файл "test2.txt"

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("res", "test1.txt"),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    list = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.forEach(System.out::println);

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("res/test2.txt");
    for(String str: list) {
      writer.write(str);
    }
    writer.close();

  }
}
```

записывает в одну строку. как сделать перевод строк в фале?

пробовал так:

```
 writer.write(str+"\n");
```

в IIDEA действительно отражает как столбик а в самом файле остаётся в строчку

Comment: вы же стримы используете, используйте стримы для записи файла. в чем проблема

Comment: если так: list.stream().Files.writeString(Paths.get("res", "test1.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); то ругается на Files. не пойму в чём ошибка

Comment: Вы правы, надо к строке добавлять перенос строки. То, что у вас при добавлении `"\n"` в файле не получились переносы -- это, наверное, редактор ожидал увидеть  `CR LF`, а `"\n"` при записи в файл записывает один `LF` (как в линуксе). Чтобы дописывать перенос строки, совместимый с вашей системой, надо делать так: `writer.write(str+System.lineSeparator());`. Либо можете вместо `writer`'а с записью каждой строки по-отдельности использовать `Files.write()` для записи списка -- он записывает переносы автоматически: `Files.write(Paths.get("test2.txt"), list, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем так сложно? Все проще...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Files.write(Paths.get("res", "test2.txt"), 
            Files.lines(Paths.get("res", "test1.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n")).getBytes());
}
```

Comment: да ваще круто одна строчка